# Recording a video with audio using GPUImageMovieWriter without jerkiness at start and end of recording?

Tags: ios6, video-capture, audio-recording, gpuimage

I am using GPUImage framework to record multiple videos one after other in close intervals with having various filters enabled in real time using GPUImageVideoCamera and GPUImageMovieWriter.

When I record the video, video starts with a jerk(freeze for half a seconds) and ends with a jerk also. I know the reason behind this are the statements in which I pass the movieWriter object to VideoCamera's audioEncodingtarget.

So In my case when I record multiple videos one after other(with different objects of GPUImageMovieWriter), the video preview view freezes at start and end of each recording.

If I remove the audio encoding target statement, conditions improves significantly but of course I don't get the audio.

Currently I am using a AVAudioRecorder while recording to save audio tracks but I believe this is not a ideal work around.

Is there any way to solve this problem.

-- I looked at the RosyWriter example by Apple, their app work almost similarly but smoothly at almost constant 30 fps. I tried to use the RosyWriter code(after removing the code that add purple effect) to save the required videos while showing GPUImageVideoCamera's filtered view to user but in vain. When applied unmodified rosywriter code just records two videos and rest video fails. I also tried to pass in the rosywriter code the capture session from GPUImageVideoCamera but only gets videos with black frames and no audio.

Please help on how can I can record GPUImage filtered videos with audio without this jerkiness. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Gaurav, did you find any solution for this issue?

Comment: @kokx I didn't find any solution directly but I have used a work around. Instead of recording multiple videos one after other, I record  a single long video and I save the NSTimeinterval at required durations. After that I create  the required videos using the saved timeintervals. But beware, recording a video of long duration using GPUImage will make the device hot. Hope that help.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and here is my workaround.

As you pointed out, this problem happened because setAudioEncodingTarget method internally calls addAudioInputsAndOutputs to set audio in/output to the capture session.

To avoid this issue, I created justSetAudioEncodingTarget method for VideoCamera as below,
(on GPUImageVideoCamera.m)

```
// just set
-(void)justSetAudioEncodingTarget:(GPUImageMovieWriter*)newValue {

if( newValue == nil ) {
    return;
}
addedAudioInputsDueToEncodingTarget = YES;

[super setAudioEncodingTarget:newValue];
}
```

The following steps is my scenario and I checked out it smoothly worked.

Called VideoCamera's addAudioInputsAndOutputs after the VideoCamera was created.
This is not right before starting the recording. :)

Set MovieWriter to the VideoCamera by justSetAudioEncodingTarget that I made above.